# Highcharts - master-detail - master with multiple color

Tags: javascript, highcharts, master-detail

I need to underline with different colors data, based on some values. I can change color in detail chart, but I need to change it in master chart too.

Here the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2msZe/35/

I have printed in console the data, and here there is color set to black.

```
{y:0.97, color:'black', flag:true}
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `turbpThreshold`, otherwise colors are not used, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2msZe/37/

```
            plotOptions: {
                series: {

                    turboThreshold: 0,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
```